# jQuery action on each single element with multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have 5 divs, all having the same styling:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjbhe2d6/)

HTML

```
<div id="box"> </div>
<div id="box"> </div>
<div id="box"> </div>
<div id="box"> </div>
<div id="box"> </div>
```

CSS

```
#box {
    background-color:blue;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

I want to execute some jQuery in order to change the colour of every specific div on `.mouseover()`, and change it back to the original on `.mouseout()`:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#box').mouseover(function() {
      $('#box').css('background-color', 'red'); 
   });

    $('#box').mouseout(function() {
      $('#box').css('background-color', 'blue'); 
   });
});
```

This only works for the first instance of the div, how would I go about making this work for every individual one? I want each div to work as it's own but I have no idea how to do that.

I researched and found out about `.each()` but I'm clueless as to how to incorporate that into my function. Can someone please help me out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique** - use class instead of ID to group similar elements

Comment: Okay, thank you for the suggestion, I will try it out right away! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As people said **ID must be always unique** and along with that if you want to achieve it `jquery` way, then you can do it as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //bind class element with '.' prefixed
  $('.box').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    //$(this) refers to current element here
  });

  $('.box').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

Using `hover` and with some performance improving aspect you can try to achieve it as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  },function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
  });
});
```

Comment: As an option, you can also use `hover()` in jQuery, but I think `:hover` in CSS is best candidate in this case

Answer (score 5):

**ID** must be **Unique**.

You can use the same class to all the elements. There is no need of using Javascript when you can use `:hover` in CSS to change the style of element on hover.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xjqs4w9f/)

```css
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.box:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't look for objects with same id, instead, you can use `.each` jquery function to look out for each div with id #box.

It looks like in this fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjbhe2d6/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "div#box" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).mouseover(function(index) {
      console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); 
   });

   $( this ).mouseout(function(index) {
       console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
      $(this).css('background-color', 'blue'); 
   });
});
});
```

Comment: This isn't correct.. **id has to be unique** in `DOM`... You are breaking the rule of creating `html` with this thus opening a space for future problems..